# Llamar a un Java desde PHP, con una lista estática

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Tengo un programa en java con un algoritmo para acceder a unos datos. En el inicio del programa, se carga una lista de BDD que durante 24 horas SIEMPRE es igual.

Mi problema es que ese Java lo inicio desde PHP, y quiero iniciarlo una vez a X hora del día, que cargue la lista de BDD, y que a partir de ahí las veces que lo llame desde PHP (que serán muchas a lo largo del día), no cargue la lista, que simplemente la tenga guardada en un objecto estático y la recoja. (Para ahorrar esos minutos que tarda en cargar la lista)

Y luego, pasadas las 24 horas, a X hora del día, se vuelva a cargar la lista porque la BDD se renovará.

¿Cómo puedo plantearme este problema?

Como me responden más abajo, he probado a hacerlo con caché, para ello he utilizado "ehcaché" de la siguiente manera:

```html
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
    .withCache("preConfigured",
      CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Long.class, String.class,
        ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100))
        .build())
    .build(true);

  Cache<Long, String> preConfigured = cacheManager.getCache("preConfigured", Long.class, String.class);

  Cache<Long, ArrayList> myCache = cacheManager.createCache("myCache",
    CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Long.class, ArrayList.class,
      ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100)).build());


  ArrayList<Generator> lista = new ArrayList<Generator>();
  lista.add(new Generator());
  lista.add(new Generator());
  lista.add(new Generator());
  lista.add(new Generator());


  //myCache.put(2L, lista);


  ArrayList<Generator> l = myCache.get(2L);
```

Pero cuando se cierra el programa la caché desaparece. ¿Hay alguna manera de tenerlo en memoria aunque el programa esté cerrado?

Comment: ¿Utiliza algún tipo de caché tipo Redis?

Comment: No, no estoy utilizando ningún tipo de caché.

Comment: Podría ser una solución interesante

Comment: Ahora mismo mi servidor es un VPS (aunque las pruebas las estoy realizando en unas Raspberri).
¿Cómo podría implementar una solución así?

Answer (score 0):

Como lo inicias?, si haces una llamada via consola, podrías recibir parámetros desde la aplicación java y manejar el cron desde el servidor que aloja los proyectos.

```
java Application arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Cron:

```
0 */2 * * *  /home/username/java Application arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Lo inicio desde php así: exec('java jar/name.jar arg0', $output);