# Llamada a java desde PHP, sin inicializar más

Tags: java, php, mysql, proceso

Mi problema es que tengo un algoritmo en java que realiza unos cálculos. A este algoritmo lo llamo desde PHP.

Pero me gustaría llamarlo por primera vez, que cargase los datos y ejecutase el código y las siguientes veces que lo llamo desde PHP, no generar una instancia nueva.

Cada vez que lo llamo desde PHP, se crea una nuevo ejecutable, que comienza el proceso de 0. Mi idea es tener un "proceso padre", al que se le llame 1 vez al día y tener varios "procesos hijos" (en el mismo proyecto de java) que se les pueda llamar independientemente de reiniciar el padre o no.

¿Esto es posible?

Comment: Puedes el código php, en donde incluyes la rutina de Java.

Comment: El código que utilizo para llamar al java es el siguiente: exec('java jar/name.jar arg0', $output);

Comment: Una de dos: 1) el proceso java lo arrancas cada vez, y lo que hace es que, según los parámetros que le pases, lee o escribe los datos de configuración en algún sitio (fichero, bd, "la nube", etc.) 2) el proceso java está continuamente en marcha y le envias mensaje. Es lo que normalmente se denomina "servicio" o "servidor".

Comment: Mi idea es lo 2º que comentas. El servidor siempre estará iniciado con unas listas cargadas y cuando le envié unos datos por php (porque accedo desde Android) realice unos cálculos.

Comment: Pues ale, a buscar documentación sobre "tutorial servidor java" (no, no se puede explicar como implementar cualquiera de las dos opciones en un par de párrafos; la pregunta es definitivamente demasiado amplia).

Comment: Si, si el servidor java sé hacerlo, pero cómo puedo comunicar PHP con un java server?

Comment: Lo más normal sería mediante HTTP: peticiones GET o POST (similar a las que hace una página web), WebServices (REST O SOAP)...

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Llamar a un Java desde PHP, con una lista estática](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76604/llamar-a-un-java-desde-php-con-una-lista-est%c3%a1tica)

Comment: Duplicada de esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76604/llamar-a-un-java-desde-php-con-una-lista-estática o viceversa.